# Wildfly 8.0.0-beta1 not showing OSGI bundles correcty

Tags: jboss, osgi, wildfly

I am having problems with OSGI bundles on Wildfly (formerly known as JBoss) 8.0.0-beta1.

I installed OSGI without issues. Then, when I launch the application server, OSGI apparently starts correctly:

```
[org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBOSGI011001: Bundle installed: org.apache.felix.log:1.0.1
[org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBOSGI011001: Bundle installed: jboss-osgi-logging:1.0.0
[org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBOSGI011001: Bundle installed: org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.6.0
[org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBOSGI011001: Bundle installed: jbosgi-wildfly-configadmin:2.1.0
[org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBOSGI011011: Starting bundles for start level: 1
[org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBOSGI011002: Bundle started: jbosgi-wildfly-http:2.1.0
[org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBOSGI011002: Bundle started: jbosgi-wildfly-jpa:2.1.0
[org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBOSGI011002: Bundle started: org.apache.felix.log:1.0.1
[org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBOSGI011002: Bundle started: jboss-osgi-logging:1.0.0
[org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBOSGI011002: Bundle started: org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.6.0
[org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBOSGI011002: Bundle started: jbosgi-wildfly-configadmin:2.1.0
[org.jboss.osgi.framework] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBOSGI011000: OSGi Framework started
```

However, when I use the management console, some important information on the bundles is apparently missing (check attached screen shot).

This is data I have using `/subsystem=osgi`:

```
{
    "activation" => "eager",
    "startlevel" => 1,
    "bundle" => {
        "0" => undefined,
        "1" => undefined,
        "10" => undefined,
        "11" => undefined,
        "12" => undefined,
        "13" => undefined,
        "14" => undefined,
        "2" => undefined,
        "3" => undefined,
        "4" => undefined,
        "5" => undefined,
        "6" => undefined,
        "7" => undefined,
        "8" => undefined,
        "9" => undefined
    },
    "capability" => {
        "javax.jws.api" => undefined,
        "javax.persistence.api" => undefined,
        "javax.servlet.api" => undefined,
        "javax.transaction.api" => undefined,
        "javax.ws.rs.api" => undefined,
        "javax.xml.bind.api" => undefined,
        "javax.xml.ws.api" => undefined,
        "org.apache.felix.log" => undefined,
        "org.jboss.osgi.logging" => undefined,
        "org.apache.felix.configadmin" => undefined,
        "org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" => undefined,
        "org.jboss.as.osgi.http" => undefined,
        "org.jboss.as.osgi.jpa" => undefined
    },
    "property" => {"org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning" => undefined}
}
```

[image: Screen Shot Of Management Console]

Comment: Something happening to me with Beta1 as well. Wanted to try CR1 but it's incompatible with JBoss OSGi 2.1.0 (latest available).

Comment: Did you file a bug ? I did not set it, so https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBOSGI-757